# How to Update data in Modal using Angular2?

Tags: html, angular, bootstrap-modal

This is My Angular2 part.Here `Updateuser` function for update data in database

```
export class UserprofileComponent 
    {
          getdata : string;     
          public data;     
           Username : any ;   
           Firstname :any;             
    updateuser(){
         let re = /[?&]([^=#&]+)=([^&#]*)/g;
         let match;
         let isMatch = true;
         let matches = {};
             while (isMatch) 
             {
                   match = re.exec(window.location.href);
                      if (match !== null)
                      {
                          matches[decodeURIComponent(match[1])] = decodeURIComponent(match[2]);
                              if (match.index === re.lastIndex)
                               {
                                    re.lastIndex++;
                               }
                        }
                        else {
                                   isMatch = false;
                             }
                  }
             console.log(matches);
             var headers= new Headers({'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded '}); 

        var body = JSON.stringify({     
           username1 : this.user.Username,
           firstname1 : this.user.Firstname,               
     })            
      this.http.post('../widgets/Update.php?ID='+matches['ID'],body, {
      headers:headers; })
       .map(res => res.json())
       .map(res => {
             if(res.success)
             {
                this.m=res.Message;
             }
             else{
                 this.m="wrong";
             }
        })
          .subscribe(
            data =>this.getdata = JSON.stringify(data),
            err => console.error(err),
            () => console.log('done'));
        }
    }
```

This is My html part:

```
 <ngl-modal header=" Edit Profile" [(open)]="opened" [size]="size">
       <div body>           
    <div class="form-horizontal" style="margin:auto;" id="editForm" *ngFor="#user of getdata">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Username:</label>
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cname" [(ngModel)]="user.Username" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Firstname:</label>
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ads" [(ngModel)]="user.Firstname"/>
            </div>    
       </div>
        <span>{{m}}</span>
      <button class="slds-button slds-button--neutral" (click)="cancel()">Cancel</button>
      <button class="slds-button slds-button--neutral slds-button--brand" (click)="updateuser()">Save</button>
    </ngl-modal>
```

Here I'd use modal for displaying the data which is display by ngFor.But I want to update this display data so how to do it?Because data is display by ngModel and when I'm taking the whole `ngModel` value for example if `[(ngModel)]="user.name"` then it showing the error that user is not define so what to do in this case??

Answer (score 0):

My first guess would be trying `let user of getdata` instead of `#user of getdata`.

My second guess would be creating an Array of users `getdata: Array<any>` as a property of your class, instead of `getdata:string`, then assign to it.

My third guess: before you get the data, there are no users, so:
    `<div *ngIf='getdata' class="form-horizontal" style="margin:auto;" id="editForm" *ngFor="#user of getdata">` to make sure you don't try to access the object before it's there.

Before you call `updateUser()` there are no objects you could show, that's why users are undefined, as far as I can see.

Hope some of this helps, good luck.

Comment: for your first guess as i m using beta version so its has to be # not let. And for your third guess its not working the way you suggested. Thankyou for your response.@bolanren